# Download image as file in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I get an image in base64 format from the database and I would like to allow the user to download the image.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you tagged this question as an Angular question, I suppose that for some reason, you dont want to expose an endpoint that serves the image in raw format, then create a link to it.

If you're looking for an Angular specific solution, there is none. However, there is a pure javascript solution described below. It can be used to preload your image so your user will be able to get the image instantly when needed.

```
let byteCharacters = atob('your base64 data');

let byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}

let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

let blob = new Blob([byteArray], {"type": "image/jpeg"});

if(navigator.msSaveBlob){
    let filename = 'picture';
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
} else {
    let link = document.createElement("a");

    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    link.setAttribute('visibility','hidden');
    link.download = 'picture';

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

You can test here : https://jsfiddle.net/pxm0eyzs/2/

Comment: you can see responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob of typescipt ,may help you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution to create file from blob stream:

```
private base64ToFile(base64Data, tempfilename, contentType) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    const sliceSize = 1024;
    const byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
    const bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
    const slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
    const byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

    for (let sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
      const begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
      const end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

      const bytes = new Array(end - begin);
      for (let offset = begin, i = 0; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
        bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
      }
      byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
    }
    return new File(byteArrays, tempfilename, {type: contentType});
  }
```

For direct downloading, I use [File-Saver library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/):

installation :

```
npm install file-saver --save
```

import section :

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
```

on download function :

```
const myFile = this.base64ToFile(stream, documentName, contentType);
FileSaver.saveAs(myFile, document.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this code it works`

```
download(row) {
    return this.Http
      .get(file_path , {
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
      })
      .map(res => {
        return {
          filename: row.name,
          data: res.blob()
        };
      })
      .subscribe(res => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = res.filename;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove();
      });
  }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

> ### On the service file

```
downloadimage(imagePath) {
    return this.http
      .get(
        imagePath,
        {
          responseType: "blob"
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          return {
            filename: row.name,
            data: res
          };
        })
      );
  }
}
```

> on the ts file subscribe downloadImage() from service file

```
downloadimage(path).subscribe(res => {
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
      a.href = url;
      a.download = "test.png";
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      a.remove();
    });
```